# Jquery fadein fadeout slideshow not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

I have having some trouble with my jquery slidshow @ http://www.willruppelglass.com/ (bottom)

As you can see the images fadein and fadeout and that works properly and the images are coming from the server and I set the height to 200 for each image. The problem I am having is that the images, after the fadeout, are still displaying and I can see them. What I am trying to do is when the image fades out don't display it, but when it fades in, display it. Is this possible?

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');


$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 6500 );   
});

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

<div id="slideshow">

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image'] ?>" height="200" class="active" />

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image2'] ?>" height="200" />

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image3'] ?>" height="200" />

</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve???

Comment: there are three images, the first one displays, fadesout becomes display none, while this is happening the second image fadesin and repeat.

Comment: btw, you should load thumbnail images in the slideshow, not sized down big image files... looks and loads horribly on first load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add animation code to fadeout the active image so the transition is smoother.
If you run all animations simultaneously you will have to tweak the timings to keep things smooth; I'm not sure why that is, but that's why I changed the duration to 2000 milliseconds.

I tested the code below and it seems to work smoothly like this. I do however want to advise you to refactor you code so that you have only 1 animation function left. You should also resize the images you use for the slideshow (5 megabytes for an image is SERIOUS overkill).

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next(): $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });

    $active.animate({opacity: 0}, 2000);
}
```

If you really only want to hide the image after the show animation is complete, you can use the code below, but that really doesn't look very smooth to me, your choice of course.

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next(): $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        $active.css({opacity: 0.0});
    });
}
```

Comment: getting them to align is a real b*tch check out helmus, http://www.willruppelglass.com/

Comment: You mean centering them equally horizontally ?

Comment: You could calculate the widths and then center the images with margins or so, its pretty tedious work ether way i'm afraid

Comment: ps - the images were uploaded onto the server and I use a database to retrieve them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9643/discussion-between-user1193385-and-helmus)

Answer (score 1):

Helmus is right your images are way too big - the first time someone visits the site, it fades through 2 or through times before the image is even downloaded. For images that size, 30kb is big, let alone 5megs. You might want to preload the images too - this one is pretty simple to use - https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded.

Not sure how you want them aligned but you can use jquery to do that too if css can't get it done.

Comment: This probably should have been a comment, not a new answer.

Comment: No, don't delete! This was what I needed to hear ;)

Answer (score 0):

Then dont apply fadeOut to the image that is to be removed from the view, just [`hide()`](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20hide&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/hide/&ei=pcZ0T-yRDsqxrAfK8rjaCg&usg=AFQjCNFHH_fxB7JbyebyWW03h1Zlv1Sx3g&cad=rja) it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using .animate() and not the built-in .fadeOut() and .fadeIn() jQuery functions?